# Nginx inside docker container not responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM nginx
```

I start a container on AWS `docker run -d --name ng_ex -p 8082:80 nginx` and :

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
6489cbb430b9        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp   ng_ex
```

And inside a container:

```
service nginx status
[ ok ] nginx is running.
```

But when I try to send a request thought browser on `my.ip.address:8082` I get a timeout error instead Nginx welcome page. What is my mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you open the 8082 port on your instance?

Comment: Yes that's was the problem. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're on an VM on aws, means that you must setup your security group to allow connection on port 8082 from all internet or only your IP/proxyIP. (The timeout may come from this).

Then `my.ip.address:8082` should works

2. If you're inside your VM get the container IP:

`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id`.

Then curl < container IP >:8082

3. If stil not working confirm on build your container `EXPOSE 80`